# sort output result in php array ksort?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, ksort

I need help, sort for this output result
bellow my website code :

```
           <?php 
           foreach ($this->system->produk as $pr_key=>$pr_val):
           if ($pr_val->status == 'on'):?>
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url(str_replace('_','-',$pr_key));?>"><?php echo $pr_val->nama;?></a>
          </li>
          <?php endif;?>
          <?php endforeach;?>
```

any idea how to sort this output ?

Comment: array("A", "B", "X", "L", "G");

result with code above :

A
B
X
L
G

I want this result to 

A
B
G
L
X

Comment: trying made code as bellow with no luck  $menu = array();
foreach ($this->system->produk as $pr_key=>$pr_val):
$menu[$pr_key] = $pr_val;

ksort($menu);
foreach ($menu as $pr_key=>$pr_val):
if ($pr_val->status == 'on'):

Comment: Are you trying to sort the keys or values of the array?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ?

```
<?php 
 sort($this->system->produk);
 foreach ($this->system->produk as $pr_key=>$pr_val):
           if ($pr_val->status == 'on'):?>
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url(str_replace('_','-',$pr_key));?>"><?php echo $pr_val->nama;?></a>
          </li>
          <?php endif;?>
  <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: sort() expects parameter

Comment: Sorry i missed a $ in front of this